# Angular ngOptions bottom element not displaying when selected

Tags: angularjs, ng-options

I have a simple select. When I select the last element in the array the input remains blank, if I then select that element again the text then appears in the input. It only happens if the last element in the array is selected the first time after refresh, all other cases work as expected.

```
<select ng-model="bib.raceDistance" ng-options="raceDistance for raceDistance in Data.defaultRaceDistances" ng-required="true"></select>
```

Data is set in a constant module

```
angular.module('core').constant('Data', {
    defaultRaceDistances: ['5km', '12km', 'Half Marathon', 'Marathon'],
});
```

The bib variable is set in the controller.

```
$scope.bib = {};
```

Why is marathon not showing up the first time it is clicked?

Thanks.

Comment: Which version of angular you are using? Can you create a plnkr/fiddle for this?

Comment: I am using Angular 1.2.28. I cannot reproduce the bug in plnkr or jsfiddle. I am thinking it must be some library I am using that is messing something up.

Answer (score 0):

try using: option with ng-repeat

```
<select ng-model="bib.raceDistance">
<option ng-repeat="raceDistance in Data.defaultRaceDistances">{{raceDistance}}</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it was just the bootstrap template I was using was not playing nice with Angular. When I went back to default bootstrap everything worked fine.

With material design templates they want you to use a different element.

Comment: Include a reference to the template you're using in question else this question and answer lacks context and won't help anyone.